# How to get Html Action Link id value using jquery and setup a new value

Tags: c#, jquery, actionlink

I have a Html Action link like below.

```
<div class="mylink"> @Html.ActionLink("SEARCH NOW", "MscHome", new { @id = "anu" }, new { @class = "linkone" })</div>
```

I need to get its `id` and set up a new one using jquery.first I tried to get the id and show it as and alert.but it shows `undefined`

```
$(".linkone").mouseenter(function () {
   //tried both ways
        alert($(this).id);
        var myval = $(".linkone").attr('id');
        alert(myval);

    });
```

Comment: I think your code did not render ID attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code and it work well:

@Html.ActionLink("SEARCH NOW", "MscHome",new { }, new { @class = "linkone",@id = "anu" })

```
 $(".linkone").mouseenter(function () {

        alert($(this).attr("id"));


    });
```